After adding the HOST setting in django, I get a utf-8 error when creating a superuser
I am new to django. I am trying to open my project with a postgresql database in docker. There is no problem in the build process, but when I try to create a superuser, I get a utf-8 error.
yml file
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: app:django
    container_name: django_container
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=project
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    container_name: postgres_db

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}

docker file
FROM python:3.12.7

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libpq-dev build-essential

WORKDIR /project

COPY requirements.txt /project/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

settings database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'firstproject',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'HOST': 'postgres_db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\django code\first\firstp\manage.py", line 22, in 
    <module>main()
File "D:\django code\first\firstp\manage.py", line 18, in 
    mainexecute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 442, in 
    execute_from_command_lineutility.execute()
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 436, in 
    executeself.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in 
    run_from_argvself.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 88, in 
    executereturn super().execute(*args, **options)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 457, in 
    executeself.check_migrations()
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 574, in 
    check_migrationsexecutor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in 
    initself.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in 
    initself.build_graph()
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in 
    build_graphself.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in 
    applied_migrationsif self.has_table():
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in 
    has_tablewith self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in 
    innerreturn func(*args, **kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 330, in 
    cursorreturn self._cursor()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 306, in 
    cursorself.ensure_connection()
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in 
    innerreturn func(*args, **kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 289, in 
    ensure_connectionself.connect()
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in 
    innerreturn func(*args, **kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 270, in 
    connectself.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in 
    innerreturn func(*args, **kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 269, in 
    get_new_connectionconnection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2_init.py", line 122, in 
    connectconn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 65: invalid start byte

I recreated my docker image. I opened a different project and tried it there but I always get a utf-8 error.

When you run your code, are you running it on the host system or in the container?  the Windows file paths don't seem to match the filesystem layout in the Dockerfile.  (If you can [edit] the question to correctly format the backtrace it would be much more readable.)

Doesn't seem to have much to do with superusers, but with connecting to the database in general. Have you perhaps copy-pasted some garbage characters into your connection settings?

Shouldn't:
depends_on: - db
Be:
depends_on: - postgres_db?
